# How to retrieve request directly from fiddler tool in java?

Tags: java, fiddler

i want to retrieve the request data which is flowing through fiddler tool(i.e http requests).so how could it be possible to retrieve the data in java programatically?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's .NET Code is available,so you may take a look of these links:

http://fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/IFiddlerExtension.asp

http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/

This may be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427533/is-there-any-java-open-source-implementation-like-fiddler